# Periodicity of words

Tags: proof-writing, combinatorics-on-words

If we have a non-periodic word $u$. Is it possible to have another word $\beta = \gamma u^{i-1}$  with $i>1$ and $\gamma \neq u^*$ so that $\beta$ is periodic.
 it's intuitive to say that it is not possible, but I don't know how to prove or disprove the statement.

Comment: What does $u^{*}$ mean?

Comment: Also, what are the specs for the alphabet?

Comment: I don't see how $\alpha$ relates to the question about $\beta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the alphabet be the set $\{x,y\}$.

Let $u = xy$, let $i=2$, and let $\gamma=xxyx$.

Then $u$ is not periodic, but
$$\beta=\gamma u^{i-1} = (xxyx)(xy) = (xxy)(xxy)$$
which is periodic.

Comment: Like I said above, if we bound the length to $\gamma$, to be less than $|u|(i-1)+2$, would it still be possible?

Comment: I answered before you suggested the bound. I'll think about it, but I'll leave my answer since it's a valid counterexample, based on your original specs.

Comment: yes you are right, according to my original question, this is the right answer, so I'll upvote and accept

Comment: Here's an interesting exercise for you to try, which I think might relate to your bounded version . . .

Comment: Let $u$ be non-periodic, and let $n > 1$. Prove or disprove: $u^n$ does not have a periodic tail $v$ such that $|v|>|u|$, and $|v|$ is not a multiple of $|u|$. I don't have a solution off-hand, but it seems like it should be true.

Comment: Perhaps I'll ask it as a question.