# periodic tail of a periodic word

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

This problem was motivated by my work on this question

$\qquad$ [Periodicity of words](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2603092)

**Problem:**

Given a finite alphabet, let $w = u^n,\;$where $n > 1,\;$and $u\;$is a non-periodic word.

Prove or disprove:$\;$If $w\;$has a periodic tail $v\;$such that $|v| > |u|,\;$then $v=u^k,\;$for some $k>1$.

**Remarks:**

It seems like it *should* be true, but I don't see an instant proof.

Suppose the claim is false.

Let $n\;$be the least positive integer for which there is a counterexample.

If $|v|\;$is a multiple of $|u|,\;$say $|v|=k|u|,\;$then it's automatic that $v=u^k$, and $k > 1$.

Thus, for our assumed counterexample, $|v|\;$is not a multiple of $|u|$.

In particular, we must have $|u| > 1$.

Since $n\;$is least, it follows that $(n-1)|u| < |v| < n|u|$.

Let $p\;$be the period of $v$.

It's clear that $p > 1,\;$else $u\;$is periodic.

Also, $p\;$can't be a multiple of $|u|,\;$else $v\;$would be power of $u$,

That's about as far as I've got.

Maybe I'm missing something simple.

Also, since this is not an area which I know much about, I wouldn't be surprised if this is a well known result, or a standard exercise. If so, please advise, and I'll delete the question.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like that $|u|$ has a period of $\gcd(p, |u|)$. (no proof yet)

Comment: Because $n$ is least, it is possible to assume that $|v|=2p$ or $|v|=3p$ (the latter only if $2p$ is a multiple of $|u|$). (informal proof, may be wrong, sorry)

Comment: baaba is a counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you are looking for seems to be Proposition 1.3.5 of [Chapter 1](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/Lothaire/lo1.ps) of [1]:

> Let $x,y \in A^*$, $n = |x|$, $m = |y|$, $d = \gcd(n,m)$. If two powers $x^p$ and $y^q$ of $x$ and $y$ have a common left factor of length at least equal to $n + m - d$ then $x$ and $y$ are powers of the same word.

Actually, if you are interested in combinatorics on words, you might be interested by the [three books](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/Lothaire/) written by M. Lothaire.

[1] M. Lothaire, *Combinatorics on Words*, Encyclopedia of Mathematics, Vol. 17, Addison-Wesley, reprinted in 1997 at Cambridge University Press.

Comment: Does this prove the statement in the question? I don't exactly understand, how this immediately proves the statement, could you explain?

Comment: So if the common factor is less than $n+m-d$, we know nothing?

Comment: The bound $n+m-d$ is tight. See Example 1.3.6 in the given reference.